# Problems adding a border to the side of a view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I'm having a problem adding a border to the bottom side of a view. When I build the project it's all fine. But when I run it, the lldb warning appears and the app stops at the delegate class and it won't show. Why is this happening?

My view that I want to add the border to:

```
fileprivate func setContainerViews()-> Void{
    //First Container
    let container : UIView = UIView()
    container.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(netHex: 0xE8ECEF)
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(container)
    container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height).isActive = true
    container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.40).isActive = true
    container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive =  true
    self.container = container
    //how I'm calling the function and adding it to the view 
    /*let optionView = drawBottomLine(optionView: container)
    self.container?.addSubview(optionView)
    */
}
```

My border adding class:

```
func drawBottomLine(optionView:UIView)->UIView{
    let bottomBorder = CALayer()
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(0.0, optionView.frame.height-1, optionView.frame.width, 0.7)
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.honePalette.accent.cgColor
    optionView.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)

    return optionView;
}
```

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash. You need to update your question with the complete error message of the crash and point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Comment: Check the outlets of your views if its get duplicated it causes a crash or add exceptional debugger and check eaxactly where app is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add `container` as a subview of itself.

In this line, you are sending in container

```
let optionView = drawBottomLine(optionView: container)
```

in the function, you add a sublayer to the container and return the container again.  Thus optionView equals container

Then in this line, you are trying to add the container to itself

```
self.container?.addSubview(optionView)
```

Thus, **remove `self.container?.addSubview(optionView)`**, but also **add `view.layoutIfNeeded()`** before you call drawBottomLine.  That way you ensure the layout has been applied, and the frames that drawBottomLine use to calculate where the border should be is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. This code to add border for only in bottom side of view in obj c.

```
CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
border.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
CGRect myVFrame = myView.frame;
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, myVFrame.size.height - 2, myVFrame.size.width, myVFrame.size.height);
border.borderWidth = 2;
[myView.layer addSublayer:border];
myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I will try to replicate this in swift